# How to detect and fix joined/overlapped letters (Segmentation for OCR) using OpenCV and Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, watershed

I'm having problem segmenting the joined or overlapped texts, for an OCR program. I'm dealing with the Times New Roman font. In this font, the letters such as fb, fh, fi, fj, fk, fl, etc are joined with each other at the top. (See pic. below). This is mostly seen in serif fonts.

Letters joining in Times New Roman font and result of watershed algorithm:
[image]

Obviously the contour detection will give these two letters a single segmentation. So, I tried the watershed algorithm. As you can see in the above picture, it does detect the overlapping but I discovered another problem in itself. The thin part of the letter 'f' is also being divided into another segment, but I want the whole 'f'. I know this is because of the marker that I'm using. (See below)

Markers that I'm using for watershed:

[image]

Also, does anyone know how to detect whether there is overlapping of letters, so that I can apply watershed algorithm to the overlapping parts only.

So how to solve this issue? Am I using the correct method, i.e. watershed to solve this? Does anyone know a better solution to this?

Comment: What things you can assume about the image you are working with? can you estimate the font size? Do you the type of the font in advance? The letters look like in the image that you added if no perspective distortion?

Comment: did you try **morphological operation**?